# How to know if I am connected to the internet by NAT or something else that assigns me a public IP address?

Tags: networking, proxy, home-networking, nat

I am connected to the internet through a proxy. When I went to [What Is My IP](http://www.whatismyip.com),  it shows a different address than that of my proxy. It's is showing the same IP address even when I connect through a different machine in the same LAN.

So can I conclude that I am using **overloading** NAT because the same IP address is assigned to all the machines in the LAN and that IP address is not the IP of the proxy server?

If so, overloading NAT uniquely identifies your machine with a port number(since the IP address is the same for all machines). But I am not able to see the port number in.

How to see my machine's port number?

Note:

[What Is My IP](http://www.whatismyip.com) shows my IP(nat or whatever) and also the proxy server's IP in the `Possible proxy Detected` section

Comment: I believe the translation information doesn't go beyond the router. Why do you need to know the port number?

Comment: @Sathya : I need to know the port number to be sure that the nat is actually mapping my ip to a public ip. As I said I also have a proxy server with a private address(not a public ip). So I have a doubt that the nat is providing a public ip to the proxy server and not to my machine. Can such a thing happen?

Comment: On large networks that's what (generally) happens. All computers talk to a caching proxy server which then connects to the Internet.

Comment: This question is unclear. The reasons for asking this question are unclear. Are you asking about NAT principles, Proxy principles, privacy of internal IP-address, function of traceroute or something else. Voting to close. Please clarify question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but generally, it's the router that handles internal address <=> external address translation and the translation method doesn't go beyond the local network.

Per you comment, on large networks, generally all requests are handled by a caching proxy server for filtering/caching/saving bandwidth and as a result, it's only the proxy server that gets assigned a public IP

Comment: how can I know the ip address of this nat router? Or how can I trace the route of my request sent from the browser?

Comment: ask your network admin. @Ashwin

Comment: how can I trace the route of my request sent from the browser?

Comment: @Ashwin ??? I don't see how this is related. use tracert

Comment: This way I will be able to find the address o the nat router. Tracert is a command line tool. I have a http proxy in my browser. How do I trace the route for my browser request?

Comment: @ashwin the command line tool might use system proxy settings else you'll have to use a third party trace route tool